# Ionic cordova build android with packageType and pass arguments to cordova hook

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, cordova-hooks

**I am on Windows OS**

I have a before_build [Cordova hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/appdev/hooks/). Inside the hook I pass arguments like this:

```
ionic cordova build android --release --configuration=ivd -- -- --ivd
```

The ivd argument is passed to the `context.opts.options.` This works fine.

I want to build my application with **packageType=bundle**.

I have seen in several posts that the way to do that is this:

```
ionic cordova build android --release -- -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

This works fine and my application builds in .aab format

**PROBLEM**

If I want to combine the two (build application in bundle mode AND pass arguments to cordova hook) it is not working

**TRIED**

```
ionic cordova build android --release -- --ivd -- -- --packageType=bundle
ionic cordova build android --release -- --ivd -- -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

and several other combinations

**WHAT WORKS**

If I do only cordova like this:

```
cordova build android --release --ivd -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

I get the desired output

**EDIT**

I answered my question but I would love a deep explanation of how the '`--`' works when running `ionic cordova` and want to combine a cordova hook

Answer (score 0):

**This worked on Windows**

```
ionic cordova build android --release --configuration=ivd -- -- --ivd -- --packageType=bundle
```

**This worked on Linux**

```
ionic cordova build android --release --configuration=ivd -- --ivd -- --packageType=bundle
```